# How to share a particular excel from Sharepoint location to a user using Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

In the current scenario, when the user submits the form , I am copying a basic excel template self service file to a sharepoint folder location. I want to share this copied file with the user who submitted the form. I am unable to share the file using flow and I am not sure, how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SharePoint's "Get file content" and then use Outlooks "Send an email" and attach the File Content where it says **Attachments Content - 1** and give it a name with the file type at the end.

[image]

**AFTER COMMENT**

You can use SharePoint’s “Create sharing link for a file or folder”

[image]

I used a OneDrive Share link in my example below, you just need to use the SharePoint one as I mentioned above.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ethan for your answer and I tried this and it works. But, is there a way to share the file though link using Power Automate? E.g when a MS form is submitted, share the link of the file with the user who submitted the form.

Comment: I just added three pictures at the bottom of my post. Hope this helps!